# Некорректно работает переход на новое окно в PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, классы, gui, pyqt

Есть **`окно_1`** и **`окно_2`**. Пользователь может перейти из **`окно_1`** в **`окно_2`** и наоборот, нажав на кнопку.

Проблема в том, что если перейти в **`окно_2`**, а затем вернуться в **`окно_1`** и попробовать снова перейти в **`окно_2`**, выдаст такую ошибку:

> NameError: **name 'SecondWin' is not defined**

Пример кода окон:

**window1.py**

```
from window2 import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout


class FirstWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.UI()
        self.UX()
        self.connections()

    def UI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(500, 300)
        self.move(400, 300)

    def UX(self):
        self.next_button = QPushButton('Следующее окно')
        self.line = QHBoxLayout()
        self.line.addWidget(self.next_button, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(self.line)

    def connections(self):
        self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.next)

    def next(self):
        self.hide()
        self.w2 = SecondWin()
        self.w2.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    w1 = FirstWin()
    w1.show()
    app.exec_()
```

**window2.py**

```
from window1 import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout


class SecondWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.UI()
        self.UX()
        self.connections()

    def UI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(500, 300)
        self.move(400, 300)

    def UX(self):
        self.next_button = QPushButton('Назад')
        self.line = QHBoxLayout()
        self.line.addWidget(self.next_button, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(self.line)

    def connections(self):
        self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.next)

    def next(self):
        self.hide()
        self.w1 = FirstWin()
        self.w1.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не надо в модуле **window2.py** создавать новые экземпляр  `self.w1 = FirstWin()`

Как вариант:

**q1513050_window1.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout

from q1513050_window2 import SecondWin

class FirstWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.next_button = QPushButton('Открыть второе окно.')
        self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.next)
        
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.next_button, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.w2 = SecondWin(self)                               # !!! +++ self
        self.w2.setWindowTitle('Second Window')

    def next(self):
        self.w2.show()
        self.hide()
#        self.w2 = SecondWin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w1 = FirstWin()
    w1.setWindowTitle('First Window')  
    w1.resize(500, 300)
    w1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1513050_window2.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, \
    QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout

#from q1513050_window1 import *                                 # НЕТ


class SecondWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):                            # !!! +++ parent
        super().__init__() 
        
        self.parent = parent                               # !!! +++ parent
        
        self.UI()
        self.UX()
        self.connections()

    def UI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(500, 300)
        self.move(400, 300)

    def UX(self):
        self.next_button = QPushButton('Открыть ПЕРВОЕ окно.')
        self.line = QHBoxLayout()
        self.line.addWidget(self.next_button, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(self.line)

    def connections(self):
        self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.next)

    def next(self):
        self.hide()
#        self.w1 = FirstWin()
#        self.w1.show()
        self.parent.show()                                        # !!! +++
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @CodeLao что не так?

Comment: Помогло, спасибо. Просто не было времени проверить

Comment: @CodeLao  пожалуйста.